# Flyout in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio

I am trying to implement Flyout in Xamarin forms. All the references that I have got are of shell.Flyout but none of them are fulfilling my requirements.

I am showing some data in a ListView and on the click of any perticular item I want the Flyout to open as shown in the mockup.

[image: Mockup for the requirement]

Please suggest any supporting library or control in Xamarin.

Comment: Do you want to `FlyoutItem` contains three Buttons? You can try to use custom renderer to achieve that with `CreateShellFlyoutContentRenderer`.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/customrenderers  Or FlyoutItem always show in Pad like this thread? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/fragments/implementing-with-fragments/

Answer (score 0):

You can try and add it for each item then control the IsVisible attribute

something like this in your Listview item template

```
    <FlexLayout Direction="Row" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
         <StackLayout FlexLayout.Basis="40%">
               <Label Text="Item"
                      HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
         </StackLayout>
         <StackLayout FlexLayout.Grow="1" Padding="5">
               <Frame IsVisible="True">
                     <!--Your Flyout here-->
               </Frame>
         </StackLayout>
    </FlexLayout>
```

But that means you have to manage them in the back code your self

changing the IsVisible attribute on the Flyout when an item of the list is clicked

Comment: Actually there are two containers on the main page. The white portion is a view on one container and the listview part is in another container

Comment: Then you can maybe add it programmatically to the right container during run time. The thing is that it would a bit more difficult to do cause you have to position it right.
it's essentially 2 lists that you have to manage the displayed items from them your self.